# Powerpoint: Fade out video clip (plus audio) on mouse click and go to next slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

Tried all kinds of things, can't seem to get it to work. What I want is this:

I have a slide with a video clip on it that automatically starts playing when the slide is loaded. This is a 3 minute clip but I want to be able to go to the next slide whenever I want (by mouse click). This works OOTB of course but the problem is that both the video and audio are abruptly cut off and I want both video and audio to fade out when I click the mouse to go to the next slide.

So: Mouse click -> fade out - next slide.

Can this be done somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really doubt can be done in PowerPoint. Actually it is hard to implement even on video players like VLC. It would be a nice feature tho.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by adding an animation to the video. I clicked the video, add exit fade, and it now fades out on my click. I had to make sure the background of the slide that the video is on was black.